# Update specific value of a database object

Tags: java, android, sql

I am currently building an inventory where the user should be able to hit a "buy" button in the item overview/main activity, which decreases the item's quantity by 1.
I already accomplished this task in another activity (detail view of the selected item) but I cannot seem to get it done in the main activity.

Here is the whole source code: https://github.com/Fedor98/InventoryApp/tree/master/app/src/main

**DetailActivity.java** (where everything works as should)

```
    /**
    * Displays details of item that wes selected in the CatalogActivity.
     */

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    /** Tag for the log messages */
    public static final String LOG_TAG = DetailActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Identifier for the inventory data loader
     */
    private static final int EXISTING_INVENTORY_LOADER = 0;

    /** Content URI for the existing item */
    private Uri mCurrentItemUri;

    /** TextView to show item's name */
    private TextView mNameTextView;

    /** TextView to show item's price */
    private TextView mPriceTextView;

    /** TextView to show item's quantity */
    private TextView mQuantityTextView;

    /** TextView to show item's supplier */
    private TextView mSupplierTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        // Examine the intent that was used to launch this activity,
        // We're creating a new item.
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mCurrentItemUri = intent.getData();

        // Change app bar to say "View Item details"
        setTitle(getString(R.string.detail_activity_title_detail_item));

        // Initialize a loader to read the item data from the database
        // and display the current values in the editor
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(EXISTING_INVENTORY_LOADER, null, this);

        // Find all relevant views that we will need to read info from
        mNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        mPriceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
        mQuantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        mSupplierTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.supplier);

        // Find the Button which will increase the item's quantity by 1
        Button increaseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increase_button);

        // Setup the item click listener
        increaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
              int quantity = Integer.parseInt(mQuantityTextView.getText().toString());
                  quantity = quantity + 1;

                  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                  values.put(InventoryEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY, quantity);

                  int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(mCurrentItemUri, values, null, null);
                  // Show a toast message depending on whether or not the increasement was successful.
                  if (rowsAffected == 0) {
                      // If no rows were affected, then there was an error with the update.
                      Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Error with increasing quantity",
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } else {
                      // Otherwise, the update was successful and we can display a toast.
                      Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Quantity increased by 1",
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }

              }
      });

        // Find the Button which will decrease the item's quantity by 1
        Button decreaseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decrease_button);

        // Setup the item click listener
        decreaseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int quantity = Integer.parseInt(mQuantityTextView.getText().toString());
                if (quantity > 0) {
                    quantity = quantity - 1;

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(InventoryEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY, quantity);

                    int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(mCurrentItemUri, values, null, null);
                    // Show a toast message depending on whether or not the decreasement was successful.
                    if (rowsAffected == 0) {
                        // If no rows were affected, then there was an error with the update.
                        Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Error with decreasing quantity",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // Otherwise, the update was successful and we can display a toast.
                        Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Quantity decreased by 1",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this,
                            "Cannot set quantity to a value lower than 0",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    [...]
    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                // Respond to a click on the "Delete" menu option
                case R.id.action_delete:
                    // Pop up confirmation dialog for deletion
                    showDeleteConfirmationDialog();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_shop:
                    purchaseItem();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    [...]

    public void purchaseItem() {
            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(mQuantityTextView.getText().toString());
            if (quantity > 0) {
                quantity = quantity - 1;

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(InventoryEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY, quantity);

                int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(mCurrentItemUri, values, null, null);
                // Show a toast message depending on whether or not the purchase was successful.
                if (rowsAffected == 0) {
                    // If no rows were affected, then there was an error with the update.
                    Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Error with purchasing product",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Otherwise, the update was successful and we can display a toast.
                    Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, "Purchase was successful",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this,
                        "Item sold out",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

**InventoryCursorAdapter.java** (where I need the onClickListener at the very end to do the same as the decrease funtionality in the method above)

```
 /**{@link InventoryCursorAdapter} is an adapter for a list or grid view
 * that uses a {@link Cursor} of inventory data as its data source. This adapter knows
 * how to create list items for each row of inventory data in the {@link Cursor}.
 */
public class InventoryCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    /** Tag for the log messages */
    public static final String LOG_TAG = DetailActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /** Content URI for the existing item */
    private Uri mCurrentItemUri;

    /**
     * Constructs a new {@link InventoryCursorAdapter}.
     *
     * @param context The context
     * @param c       The cursor from which to get the data.
     */
    public InventoryCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, 0 /* flags */);
    }

    /**
     * Makes a new blank list item view. No data is set (or bound) to the views yet.
     *
     * @param context app context
     * @param cursor  The cursor from which to get the data. The cursor is already
     *                moved to the correct position.
     * @param parent  The parent to which the new view is attached to
     * @return the newly created list item view.
     */
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Inflate a list item view using the layout specified in list_item.xml
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    /**
     * This method binds the inventory data (in the current row pointed to by cursor) to the given
     * list item layout. For example, the name for the current item can be set on the name TextView
     * in the list item layout.
     *
     * @param view    Existing view, returned earlier by newView() method
     * @param context app context
     * @param cursor  The cursor from which to get the data. The cursor is already moved to the
     *                correct row.
     */
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Find individual views that we want to modify in the list item layout
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_catalog);
        final TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity_catalog);
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price_catalog);

        // Find the columns of item attributes that we're interested in
        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME);
        final int quantityColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY);
        int priceColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_PRICE);

        // Read the item attributes from the Cursor for the current item
        String itemName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
        String itemQuantity = cursor.getString(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(quantityColumnIndex)));
        String itemPrice = cursor.getString(priceColumnIndex);
        itemPrice = itemPrice + "€";

        // Update the TextViews with the attributes for the current item
        nameTextView.setText(itemName);
        quantityTextView.setText(itemQuantity);
        priceTextView.setText(itemPrice);

        mCurrentItemUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(InventoryEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);

        // Find the Button which will decrease the item's quantity by 1
        Button saleButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sale_button);

        // Setup the item click listener
        saleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
```

Thank you for any help in advance. I am so lost, sitting here since days and not getting any further...

Comment: So you know how to make things work if the Views (Button, EditText) are not part of a list row?

Comment: I seem to be only missing the correct update call. As I retrieve and update quantity correctly when hitting the sale button in catalog activity. But the value does not get updated in the database.

Comment: Now I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question very well. What exactly are the steps when the user clicks the "saleButton"? How do you retrieve the quantity, what (besides the database) do you update, and how do you try to update the database? I would have guessed you'd do it just like in the details activity (and so maybe adding  "final" in the right places might be helpful )

Comment: When the user clicks on the sale button, the quantity of the respective item should decrease by 1, the specific entry in the database should be updated accordingly. Yes, the steps should be the same as in the details activity, but somehow the ContentResolver update call does not seem to work in the CatalogActivity